# is it Possible to remove the last inserted text in div control through jQuery in Asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox, append

new Jquery I am inserting text to div control,when check box checked. and i want to remove  that text when uncheck `checkbox'

```
<div align="center" id="chkBoxes">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chbIceCream" text ="Ice Cream" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chbCake" Text ="Cake" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" />
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chbChocolet" Text ="Cho colet"  runat="server" />    
 </div>
 <div id="ContentDiv"> 
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#chbIceCream').click(function () {
         var Text = $("input:checkbox[id$=chbIceCream]").next().text();
         if ($(this).attr('checked'))
             $('#ContentDiv').append(Text);
         else
            $('#ContentDiv').remove(Text);
      });
  });
```

Comment: What purpose you are writing this $("input:checkbox[id$=chbIceCream]").next().text() ? What text you want to fetch?

Comment: check box `chbIceCream` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the text from ContentDiv then see Matthew's answer

if you want to remove specific text i.e. there is other text in that div too, which you do not want to remove. then use:

```
var str = $('#ContentDiv').text()
str.replace('your text','');
$('#ContentDiv').text(str);
```

in your `else` part

Answer (score 1):

Try with [**text**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [**empty**](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) functions

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#chbIceCream').click(function () {

    var Text = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).attr('checked'))
        $('#ContentDiv').text(Text);
    else
       var oldText= $('#ContentDiv').text();
           $('#ContentDiv').text(oldText.replace(Text, ""));
  });
});
```

**Edit:** Updated answer based on comment in question
Updated **$(this).val()** from $(this).next().text()

Comment: i know this method.... but what i want is remove that specified checkbox text only. Once try with ur code it will give inaccurate text @Murali

Comment: @Radix then you can simply try with simple string replacement method available in javascript. Please see my updated answer